# Is it possible to disable AutoPostBack on LinkButton click in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

In the following code I am trying to prevent autopostback, to not to load the page again. But this is not working. Is there any other way I can disable AutoPostBack on button click ? I know there is no autopostback property for LinkButton but I want to know if I can do it.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="myBtn"  onclick="myBtn_Click" CssClass="btn" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no default property to set `AutoPostBack` for `LinkButton`. But you can add HTML attributes to do that.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="myBtn" onclick="myBtn_Click" CssClass="btn" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Add this in the `Page_Load` event which will stop the event from Client Side.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
}
```

or more simply with `OnClientClick`

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="myBtn" onclick="myBtn_Click" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="function(){ return false; }"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Or just OnClientClick="return false;"